# Intution behind conditional expectation when sigma algebra isn't generated by a partition

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I'm struggling with the concept of conditional expectation, when the sigma algebra on which it is conditioned isn't generated by a partition.

If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability field such that $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by a partition $\Lambda_n$.

Then we know that:

$E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ = $E_1$$[X|\mathcal{F}]$ $I(\omega \in \Lambda_1)$ +$E_2$$[X|\mathcal{F}]$ $I(\omega \in \Lambda_2)$ + $E_3$$[X|\mathcal{F}]$ $I(\omega \in \Lambda_3)$ + .....

Where $E_i[.]$ is the expectation calculated as per the conditional probability $P(.|\Lambda_i)$

Hence when $\omega$ is in $\Lambda_i$ the conditional expectation gives the expectation of random variable X given that the observed event is $\Lambda_i$ and hence use the modified conditional probability rather than the original one. However this interpretation is only valid as long as the conditioning sigma algebra is generated by a partition. Is there a similar interpretation for a general case?

i.e what will it physically represent?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Best,
Adwait

Comment: It looks to me that you are  assuming  that $\mathscr{F}$ is generated by a partition, not  $\mathscr{A}$. If $\mathscr{A}$ where generated by a partition and $X$ were $\mathscr{A}$ measurable, then $X$ would be constant on each of the parts $\Lambda_k$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo! Replaced $\mathcal{A}$ with $\mathcal{F}$

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is the right place to ask this question as it isn't really research level (see FAQ), please ask at math.stackexchange.com instead. [Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation?]

Comment: Yup have read the wikipedia article. But it doesn't give an intuitive explanation for general sigma algebras. Have posted it here since I didn't find any (satisfactory) explanation in a graduate level text book. 

Comment: Apparently simultaneously crossposted at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

The best intuition that I have for conditional expectation is that it's a projection. Also, try thinking about the conditional expectation as a Radon Nikodym derivative.